# Is it secure to use self signed certificate on FTP but not in HTTPS? Why?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to generate self signed certificates (SSC) for most of the local services. Cryptography has been a bit complicated to understand, mostly the PKI.

Is there any conceptual reason why we don't use SSCs on HTTPS, but seems to be fine (may be wrong here) for FTP secure?

This is the way I'm generating any of them, instead of a certificate signing request:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.pkey -out server.cert
```

Comment: “Is there any conceptual reason why we don't use SSCs on HTTPS, but seems to be fine (may be wrong here) for FTP secure?” - You control what FTP client you use.  You cannot control what browser someone will use to connect to your website.  Users are trained to be suspicious of any websites that indicates it’s not secure.  Anyone using a FTP client knows what they are doing.  You don’t use a browser to connect to a FTP server

Comment: Upvoted. I agree to the above, save that "anyone using an ftp client knows what they are doing".  In my experience, there are a swathe of "wannabee web designers" who dont understand ftp or security but use ftp anyway.

Comment: @davidgo - Perhaps I can word that statement differently.  Your not sending your a credit card number while connected to a FTP server.  It for necessarily need to be encrypted.  You only have to be worried about the initial connection when the username and password is submitted and authenticated.  Furthermore, connecting to a FTP is more involved then browsing a website.

Comment: @davidgo that statement is quite nasty imho. No one is born knowing, and sometimes everyone uses tools they don't fully understand. You should know this. Also, some people are just curious and have nothing to do with web development; and "wannabee web designers" isn't a nice term. I've read about ssh, openssl, pki, ftp manual pages etc, and that's all you should care about if anything.

Comment: @Minsky I apologise if this came across badly (and I cant edit a comment). I mean't no disrespect - A number of people I deal with a lot - and have a great deal of respect for would fall into this category - they are better then I am for the graphics and maybe even working in Wordpress, but they dont have the knowledge to be professional web designers and know it.  (For that matter, I genuinely consider myself a wannabee web developer - albeit for entirely different reasons - I suck at graphic design and Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The assumption in other answers here is that HTTPS is only used for browsing the web by general consumers.  Granted, that a huge majority of HTTPS traffic is the web, but the two are only protocols, and there are edge cases (e.g. a REST based API) where HTTPS could be as specialist as FTP, in which case the argument for and against self-signed certs don't differ.

A service where two end-points communicate over HTTPS and it's unlikely to expand, could be, and often is, operated with self-signed. There is no difference from the point of view of the protocols, only the use case.

PKI signed certificates come into their own when there's a one-to-many relationship between the end-entity (server) and relying parties (clients).  Self-signed certificates in this scenario would be cumbersome as clients would individually need to review and trust each server certificate (ignoring things like Windows Group Policy for trust-anchor distribution).  If you extrapolate this to multiple servers, such as the WWW, then the challenge gets even larger.  Add into the mix the fact that most users of the WWW aren't tech-savvy then self-signed become a burden.

On the other hand, setting up a full PKI for two machines to communicate is overkill, given the overhead of running a secure PKI service. If all you're doing is sending a file between two servers, or sending a REST API message between two machines, then self-signed certificates could be considered acceptable here.  During the configuration of the two end-points, most probably by tech-savvy admins, they could review the certificate and install it.

A compromise is to use commercial CA, where the work of operating a trusted CA is done for you.  There's no need to operate a PKI and certificates are trusted by many potential users.  The only additional workload is that the operator of the server will need to enrol for a certificate from the CA (possibly for a fee) and install that on their server instead of generating a self-signed.  This assumes that your machines are connected to the Internet though.

On a similar note to the previous paragraph, your organisation may operate their own internal PKI, and clients already have the root CA certificate in their trust-anchor store.  The discussion for and against self-signed vs CA signed become fuzzier now as there's little extra effort involved in using a CA signed certificate.

The bottom line is: HTTPS or FTPS as protocols don't care whether you use CA signed or self-signed certificates.  You need to analyse your requirements on a case-by-case basis and decide what model to use.

Comment: Your post is - by the most generous description - confusing/misleading.  Its worth noting that PKI stands for Public Key Infrastructure and a CA is a Certification Authority. Other then lack of trust accorded by OS's and browsers by default etc, the CA I run for my use is conceptually no different and is still a CA. REST and other API's act at a different layer to https and ftps and do not require these protocols, and ftps protocol and https are nothing alike, save perhaps for the libraries they use to negotiate tls.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the threat model, reason for using SSL and user base.

In the general/arbitrary case where external users are transferring mildly critical data across the wider Internet  both certs should be signed by a 3rd party.

On the other extreme  if only a handful of devs need it, a self signed cert can simply be accepted as a one off per ftp client and this is less work and as safe.

There is also the practical aspects to consider - many (most?) people dont care or understand that much about security.  HTTPS has bevome the standard of the web because Google pushed it that way by making it a ranking factor, and then tweeking their browser...  There us no such driver behind sftp.

Another element is ease of creation. Using cpanel or letsencrypt on a publicly accessible web server makes it easy to systematically renew certs - while less likely true for sftp for a number of reasons- including that many domains share a single ftp host often requiring an impractically complex ssl cert to "just work"

If you dont really care about the security of a self signed cert , why sign it for only 365 days? You will likely reduce your hassle by making it valid for many years.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any conceptual reason why we don't use SSCs on HTTPS, but seems to be fine (**may be wrong here**) for FTP secure?

I think you are wrong here, i.e. it is not acceptable.

But, FTP is a dying technology as for example shown by the major browsers removing support for it. There only comparably few FTP servers in the first place, at least compared to the number of web sites. Even less of these support FTPS (which is not the same as SFTP), i.e. FTP with TLS. And the major browser never supported FTPS in the first place.

So what you have is essentially the junk yard of the internet, mostly abandoned technology which is only kept for some special cases. General public access is usually not one of these any more since it got replaced by HTTP and HTTPS. So one can say that nobody cares a lot what happens there.

Still, it is not acceptable. In times where certificates are easy to get and free (Let's Encrypt and others) it is not that much of an effort any more to get a proper certificate instead of a self-signed.

Comment: FTP's imminent death is much over-hyped, and has been for a long time.  As much as I would like to see it dead as it is an awful protocol - 2 related tcp streams for a simple file transfer- really??? - it fills an important niche which has not been fully superceded (It is a well known standard, and is a lot easier to jail and [from a server POV] separate and virtualise then the SCP suite of clients and is more standardised then webdav.)

Comment: @davidgo: I agree with you that FTP fills in important niche - but it is still a  small niche. And the niche is not filled by FTP due the superiority of the protocol but due the amount of implementations available for it - even though most don't support FTPS and many which do traditionally skipped certificate validation (even Perl, PHP, Python, ruby ... did this in the past - only these changed the behavior). Still, I don't consider use of self-signed certificates acceptable. But many don't care much what happens with  this (slowly but steadily) dying technology.